# htaccess limit max length variables

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

First of all this works already but i want to limit some variable lengths.
any other improvement of my code is also welcome

```
RewriteEngine on 
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase / 

RewriteRule pict/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+) retpic.php?type=$1&id=$2 [L]

RewriteRule pc/(.*) pcs/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9]+) index.php?ln=$1&id=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/retpic.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pcs/.*$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^11\.11\.11\.11

RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

retpic.php distributes my pictures where:
`([a-z]+)` is a 2letter indicator on size and type of picture
`([0-9]+)` is a 6digit id of what picture i want

is it possible to limit these to being max 2and6 characters long?

the same goes for my index:
`([a-z]+)` a 2letter language indicator being (en, de, li, nl)
`([0-9]+)` a 6digit id of what page to show.

the pcs folder contains my css and js files in a multi level folder structure
and should be freely accessible

the last part i use to redirect every faulty url to my index except for my ow ip adress
so i can access my cms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use range regex construct `{...}` to force length:

```
RewriteEngine on 
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase / 

RewriteRule pict/([a-z]{2})/([0-9]{6})/?$ retpic.php?type=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule pc/(.*)$ pcs/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([0-9]{6})/?$ index.php?ln=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/retpic.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pcs/.*$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^11\.11\.11\.11
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Great that works like a charm.

only why do you add $ to pc/(.*)?
and why the use of QSA i was under the impression this is mostly used for testing?

Comment: You're welcome. `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.